# Using a presenter with Inherited Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources, presenter

I use the excellent Inherited Resources gem quite a bit in my Rails apps, but whenever I want to use a presenter I fall back to writing controllers by hand.

Is there a good, clean solution for combining Inherited Resources with something like Draper or delegate_presenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of `delegate_presenter` here.

`delegate_presenter` should work just fine with `inherited_resources`. Now I haven't actually used inherited_resources on a project, so a lot of this is just from the readme.

What I always to do create the presenter object in the view anyway: `todo_present = Present(@todo)`, for example.

If you are having templates from a common source (like `LegalTodo` is a subclass of `Todo`, for some bog-unknown reason), and you share templates, you could do this in your template:

`presenter = Present(resource)`

`resource` - at least according to the inherited_resources readme - is the helper for the current resource your looking at (so, `@todo`, or `@legal_todo`)

`Present()` will look at the class of the object and instantiate the appropriate presenter object. `TodoPresenter` if `resource` returns a `Todo` object, `LegalTodoPresenter` if `resource` returns a `LegalTodo` object.

Then, assuming those presenters are polymorphic, the presenters will let you abstract the differences away ("The name of a `LegalTodo` be the description + deposition number, but the name of the `Todo` item should just be description") - even if you share views!